# Android RSA key pair generation with keysize as 8192 returns "Failed to generate key pair"

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, rsa, android-keystore

I am trying to generate RSA key pair with key size as 8192, with padding as OAEP and digest as SHA1. But getting error as "Failed to generate key pair"

Code snippet as below:

```
val keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore")
keyGen.initialize(KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("Key1", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA1)
                    .setKeySize(8192)
                    .build())
val keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair()
```

Please suggest a solution to solve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The maximum size of an RSA key supported by the Android keystore is 4096 bits, s. [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#SupportedKeyStoreKeys) and [KeyPairGenerator](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#SupportedKeyPairGenerators).

Answer (score 2):

With KeyPairGenerator, the key size must be between **256** bits and **4096** bits. So you need to change setKeySize().